# Indispensable flags for compiling and running java code

Tags: java, flags

I've started learning java today, using the current JDK for compiling/running and notepad++ as editor. I dont't want to use IDE's until I've understood how things work by doing them myself and not klicking some button, so I'm using shellcommands for compiling and running my first simple programs.

Unfortunately, most tutorials I've found are covering examples using NetBeans or Eclipse, so at the end some button gets pressed and the magic begins.

I understand what happens when I compile code with javac and run it in the JVM, but I need serious clues to know if it happens in the right way.

I know, that flags are very suitable for that purpose and allow me to control nearly all steps of the compilation process done by javac and during runtime by the JVM, but the official list of flags provided by oracle is absolutely overwhelming.

So, as suggested by the title, I'm searching for some reference mentioning and explaining the most important flags which are necessary to compile and run java code secure and stable. Anything I've found till now is either not caring about this, using default's configuration of an IDE or something that deals with flags on a level far above mine, so I decided to ask here for further advance.

Comment: if you simply type `javac` or `java` and hit enter, you will get all the options they use. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: NetBeans and Eclipse support many different kinds of projects, but most of them use build tools like `ant` and `maven`. These tools use textual configuration and build scripts and thus IDEs simply maintain them (look for `*.xml` files in your project directory) and then ask `ant` or `maven` to do the work when a button is clicked.

Comment: @mariusm: Does this mean, the XML-files contain (at all) the same information about how the compiling process should be done I would normally type into the shell? I wasn't aware that IDE's do it that way, so maybe they could be more interesting for my current purpose than I thought. Thanks!

Comment: @Little Child: You hit the point! Awww... I can't believe I spent ours searching. This solution is really the egg of Columbus!

Comment: I have just recognized that this old question of mine has been closed as off-topic. I am sorry that my question did not meet the standards, but it is unclear to me, why this is the case here. I am a bit surprised, to say the least, that non of the closers has mind to left a comment about the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply type `javac` or `java` and hit enter, you will get all the options they use.  Your output will be something like this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\StackOverflow>java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.
```

Similarly, you'll get the output for `javac`.